# How to find out what's adding whitespace on a web page?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I'm specifically wondering about this page: https://podato.herokuapp.com/#/podcasts/http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.twit.tv%2Ftwig.xml/

Why is the text of each item not alligned with the image on the left?

But a more general question: how do I debug this sort of thing? What's the best way to find out where whitespace is coming from?

Comment: What do you mean by aligned with the image on the left? opening your link, the text of each image appears to the immediate right of the image. What orientation are you looking to achieve?

Comment: There's a list of podcast episodes. Each episode text should align with its image on the left.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging you could use the built-in developer tools. 
For official guides: 
Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/part1/ 
Firefox: http://www.howtogeek.com/105320/how-to-use-firefoxs-web-developer-tools/ 
 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools

Also for Firefox i know there is [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), a tool developed to make debugging somewhat easier.

To answer your question, take a look at Vikas Kapadiya's answer, in your body tag is a line-height: 1.5; declared. Try and change it in the developer tools to see what happens.

**Edit**

A possible solution could be wrapping the span elements in a seperate div. I'm thinking of adding a negative top margin. Feel free to come up with other methods, this is the first one i think of.

The reason i'd choose for a div is because it is a block element, whereas span elements are inline elements, which are unable to add a negative top margin to. Also i noticed that you use a data-reactid? I guess it would be a bit cleaner if you could add that to the container div, so the span elements (and the br tag) are free of the data-reactid. Don't know if that is desirable, but see for yourself what would be best.

```
div.data {
    margin-top: -5px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, and it reduces the misalignment, but doesn't completely fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in basscss line no 121

```
body {
line-height: 1;
}
```